# Test if imported (Gmsh) knitted fabric T-yarn mesh has volume?

Tags: mesh

I am interested to do meshing for woven T-yarn and Knitted S-yarn as is shown in the figure below in blender. I am using [Gmsh](http://gmsh.info/) to convert standard triangle language to volume mesh.

I am looking for having a mesh to 8 T-yarn and single T-yarn, I follow some videos how to do that, however, in the single T-yarn, it seems there is no actual volume even the tetrahedron seems not optimized.

My question is: How to check whether there is an actual volume mesh in my example of single T-yarn.

From the left is the stl files and the right is the Gmsh software where I am trying to convert to volume mesh.

[image]

Comment: Could you reduce the two paragraphs before the question, they don't appear relevant to me. And could you expand on the actual question. What is an *actual* volume mesh? Do you mean "If the mesh is non-manifold" maybe?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not experienced which part doesnot sound relevant? on the left is the stl file and on the right: it is supposed the volume mesh.

Comment: Please answer both questions in my comment, you forgot: *Do you mean "If the mesh is non-manifold" maybe?*

Comment: Include a description what a "volume mesh" is please.

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand what do you mean by non-manifold in the context of meshing. A volume mesh is defined here in that example since I have been using it and come across what is volumetric mesh: https://softroboticstoolkit.com/sofa/tutorial/step-1

Comment: It doesn't say "volume mesh" in that article, is says "volumetric mesh". I think you want to check for **non manifoldness**, please research it.

Comment: okay I will search about non-manifoldness, can I ask is there a difference between volumetric and volume mesh, I though they are the same

Comment: Maybe, but if you got a source, where we can read about what you want, then use the terminology of that source. Btw, you can always edit your question to include more information. For example that the left is the imported (?) stl (?) in blender (?) or the link to the tutorial.